# How to avoid archival logs creation while Materialized view refresh

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, materialized-views

For my application using two Materialized views for application general search. Whenever user made changes on master tables i use stored procedure to refresh corresponding MVs. 
To make MVs available while on refreshing, I configured refresh logics as below

*DBMS_SNAPSHOT.REFRESH('MV_VIEW_1',atomic_refresh=>FALSE);*
*DBMS_SNAPSHOT.REFRESH('MV_VIEW_2',atomic_refresh=>FALSE);*

However recently found that this causing more DB archival logs creating in the server. I tried with MVs with  *nologging*  option and still having same issue.

Look for any recommendation for avoid this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Applying fast refresh minimize the redo logs.

DBMS_SNAPSHOT.REFRESH('MV_VIEW_1','F'); 
DBMS_SNAPSHOT.REFRESH('MV_VIEW_2','F');